# Show that if the sequence $(x_n)$ is weakly convergent to $x_0 \in X$, then $||x_0|| \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} ||x_n||$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The question is the following:

> Show that if the sequence $(x_n)$ in a normed linear space $(X,|| \cdot ||)$ is weakly convergent to $x_0 \in X$, then
>   $$
> ||x_0|| \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} ||x_n||
> $$

Here is my attmpt:

> Assume that $(x_n)$ in a normed linear space $(X, ||\cdot||)$ is weakly convergent to $x_0 \in X$. Namely, for every bounded linear function $\varphi \in X^*$
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi(x_n) = \varphi(x_0)
> $$
>   We now first assume that $(x_n)$ are nonzero. By Hahn-Banach Theorem, choose a bounded linear function $\varphi'$ satisfying
>   $$
> ||\varphi'|| = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \varphi' (x) = ||x||
> $$
>   Therefore
>   $$
> \varphi'(x_n) = ||x_n||\quad \text{and} \quad \varphi'(x_0) = ||x_0||
> $$
>   By the weak convergence, we have
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi'(x_n) = \varphi'(x_0) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} ||x_n|| = ||x_0||
> $$
>   Now if $(x_n)$ are zero, then the limit is also zero, and the result is trivial. If $(x_n)$ are nonzero, but the limit is zero, then 
>   $$
> \liminf_{n \to \infty}{||x_n||} \geq 0 = ||x_0||
> $$
>   Here we can conclude the result.

which fails because the choice of $\phi'$ is not valid (Thanks @Kabo Murphy). Then how can I do this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your argument is not valid. How do you get $\phi'(x_n)=\|x_n\|$?

Comment: @KaboMurphy By the definition of $\phi'$? Since $\phi'(x) = ||x||$.

Comment: You can find $\phi'$ such that $\phi'(x)=\|x\|$ for  a **particular** $x$. You cannot find one $\phi'$ which works for all $x$,so you cannot replace $x$  by $x_n$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Oh, thanks for you help!!! I just got it. Then this attempt fails. How can I approach this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\phi \in X^{*}$ such that $\|\phi \|=1$ and $\phi (x_0)=\|x_0\|$. Then $|\phi(x_n)| \leq \|\phi \| \|x_n\|=\|x_n\|$. Take $lim \inf$ on both sides. Since $\phi(x_n) \to \phi(x_0)$ we get  $\|x_0\|=|\phi (x_0)| \leq \lim \inf \|x_n\|$.

Comment: Thanks!! At least my attempt was close.